# insert into python mysql not updating in DB

Tags: python, mysql

I tried inserting the values into the DB through python. However i do not get any error but i do not see it updating in DB. Please advice.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

val = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='root123', 
db='expenses')

def access_db(val):
    access = val.cursor()
    sql = """Insert into monthly values (2,'Food',1000)"""
    access.execute(sql)
 val.commit()
 val.close()
```

Output from DB after the script execution:

```
MariaDB[expenses]> select * from monthly;
SL_no     Type    Amount
  1       Fuel     500
```

I do not find the second entry in Db.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you are calling the `access_db()` function anywhere

Comment: My bad. Thanx for the help